# Control in Visual Studio keeps going to random files

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and when executing any program, the control abruptly goes to random files like `crtexe.c`  or `print.c` etc. I don't understand why this keeps happening. Any sort of help would be appreciated thank you! 
The output window shows the below message.

The thread 0x22ec has exited with code 34 (0x22).

The thread 0xa14 has exited with code 34 (0x22).

The program '[9972] Spoj.exe' has exited with code 34 (0x22).

Comment: More information as to what you're trying to do is necessary. With just the amount of information that you provided, I'm not sure how much someone can help.

Comment: @Fizz Thank You !  Added information about what the output window says, hope it is clear now!

Comment: How are you "executing" your program? Does "any program" apply just to the one(s) you're running? Are other programs on your PC working fine? What happens if you start with a brand-new project in Visual Studio? Does that die in the same way?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yes, even if i am running my previous projects,or any brand new project, it's happening the same way.If printf statement is being executed it jumps to print.c , if return statement gets executed, it jumps to crtexe.c

Comment: Your programs are all crashing inside the C runtime library. Reinstall Visual Studio.